# I 've "function not define" error with JPEG format

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've an error. I want send a picture welcome message on discord with my bot with this code :

I don't now hox fix the problem and where did the error come from

```
    bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage("./assets/wallpaper.jpg");
    const applyText = (canvas, text) => {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Declare a base size of the font
        let fontSize = 70;

        do {
            // Assign the font to the context and decrement it so it can be measured again
            ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
            // Compare pixel width of the text to the canvas minus the approximate avatar size
        } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);

        // Return the result to use in the actual canvas
        return ctx.font;
    };
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Slightly smaller text placed above the member's display name
    ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText('Welcome to the server,', canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 3.5);


    // Add an exclamation point here and below
    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);



    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    channel.send(attachment);
});
```

And the error :

> (node:1428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   TypeError: `member.user.displayAvatarURL` is not a function
>       at Client. (C:\Users\Eleve\Desktop\FA Bot\index.js:129:52)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>
> (node:1428)  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
>   This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch().
>   To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:1428) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: As the error already says: `member.user.displayAvatarURL` is not a function. [This commit](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/commit/577ab37a2b5adedaa31e8896a96d0a540f8de726) made it a method so are you using a really old discord version?

Comment: No, I use the lastest version